# How to make two equal unittest.mock.Mock objects to be of the same type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I have to ensure that a Sequence is homogeneous, i.e. contains only objects of similar type. So I added an assert like `assert all(isinstance(obj, type(my_list[0])) for obj in my_list[1:])` That's not perfect but sufficient for my needs. Unfortunately this causes problems when using it with `unittest.mock.Mock`:

```
import unittest.mock as utm

class C:
    pass

my_list = [utm.Mock(spec_set=C), utm.Mock(spec_set=C)]

all(isinstance(obj, type(my_list[0])) for obj in my_list[1:])
>>>
False
```

In particular two mocks have different types, even if the have the same `spec_set`:

```
isinstance(utm.Mock(spec_set=C), type(utm.Mock(spec_set=C)))
>>>
False
```

Is there any way to configure the mocks so they are considered to be of the same type? Modifying the check would be an option too, as long as it does not get mock specific.

If that is of interest: I used Python  3.5.

Answer (score 0):

why not do this?

```
class A:
    pass

class MockA(Mock, A):
    pass

a1 = MockA()
a2 = MockA()

assert isinstance(a1, MockA) == isinstance(a2, MockA)
```

Comment: Well this would mean I have to write the whole mock myself. Of course my `class C: pass` was just an example to outline the problem at hand. The real use case uses much more sophisticated classes - so this is not really an option.

Comment: then what about monkey patching the class in tthe test module?